# jquerymobile confirm doesn't seem to be affecting outcome?

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, confirm, preventdefault

Here's a snippet from a jquerymobile application. It's a simple file-manager that allows files to be deleted, and I want to confirm the delete. I'm attempting to use a javascript *confirm* to double check whether an action should continue; but it seems that no matter what I do, I can't **stop** it from happening.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".confirm").live("click",function(ev){
            var nam = $(this).html(),
                loc = $(this).attr('href'),
                answer = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete:\n\n" + nam);
            if (answer){
                return true;
                //window.location.href = loc;
            }else{
                ev.preventDefault();
                return false;
                window.location.href = window.location.href;
            }
        });
    });
</script>

...

<div data-role="page" data-theme="a">
    <div data-role="content">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
            ...
            <li><a class="confirm" href="?delete=#urlEncodedFormat(f.name)#">#f.name#</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can see that I've tried 3 different methods to prevent the link from redirecting the page, but none of them seem to be doing what I had hoped. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You're using `.live` without understainding how it does the magic.

Change `.live` to `.bind` and it will work.

Also - read about `.live` to get the knowledge that `.live` binds to document and catches the events as they bubble up, so it's far too late to prevent default actions or anything.

And BTW - if you put code after a return statement there is this slight possibility that somebody could get confused into thinking that it is actually being run for some weird reason.

[edit]

If you want it to work without javascript (progressive enhancement and stuff) then you should go with dialogs generated server-side for the purpose of asking the question even if there's no javascript.

If you don't care about progressive enhancement and want it to work only in high-end browsers, then why do you bother with a href?
rename `href` into `data-href` and load it if the user confirms. You won't have to prevent anything.

Comment: You were right that I misunderstood `.live`, but `.bind` won't work for me either, as the list items are loaded via ajax. The file system being browsed is much to large to pre-load the whole thing, so it only loads one directory at a time. I tried using `.bind` (I had actually tried `.click`, originally) and it still doesn't do what I'd like. I may just try switching to jquerymobile dialogs to see if I can get that working.

Comment: Yes. `bind` differs from `live`. I did ajax-heavy projects with jquery before it had the `live` method and I had to figure it all out. You handle the ajax calls yourself, so why not just bind new clicks to whatever you load? That's how it was done in the old times ;) Also - see my edit

Comment: I got it working with the jqmobile dialog functionality. I'm not terribly worried about progressive enhancement because it's an app to use in my house, by me, on my devices, and I have no intention of turning JS off.